# How to call custom methods of a role provider?

Tags: c#, roleprovider

OK, I've created my custom role provider and added it to the web.config. Here's part of my code for the role provider:

```
public class MyCustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public string MyCustomFunction()
    {
        return "its my custom string";
    }
}
```

When I need to use the role provider in my application, I'll call it like this:

```
var truth = Roles.IsUserInRole("myUsername", "myFakeRole");
```

OK, Great!, it calls my custom code (I can tell from debugging) and returns true every time. Why can I not make the following call on my custom role provider?

```
var no_compile = Roles.MyCustomFunction();
```

how can I make all public members of my custom role provider accessible?

Comment: Have you tried casting `Roles` to `MyCustomRoleProvider`? Ex. `((MyCustomRoleProvider)Roles).MyCustomFunction();` I highly doubt this is the 'correct' way to do it but it may at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: No, that does not work. I've also tried `Roles.Provider.MyCustomFunction()` does not work.

Comment: However, `((MyCustomRoleProvider)Roles.Provider).MyCustomFunction()` works. This is a bit more cumbersome than I would have hoped...  I guess I'll have to use it.

Comment: Ha! I'm glad you at least found something. Thanks for the update :-)

As a side note, you might be able to implement `MyCustomFunction()` as a static extension method. That way you could call it 'seamlessly' without the extra wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

I do not really know what is the problem, but you should be able to do

```
var no_compile = _Roles.MyCustomFunction();
```

If `_Roles` defines a new `MyCustomRoleProvider` since the function is public

**Example**

```
MyCustomRoleProvider _Roles = new MyCustomRoleProvider();
var no_compile = _Roles.MyCustomFunction();
```

**Notice that**: You can not call `MyCustomRoleProvider.MyCustomFunction()` directly because it is not a `public static string`.

**Notice that**: `System.Web.Security.Roles` is a class which contains the same function name of your class `IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)` but the function is not the same in both classes. So, you can not access `Roles.MyCustomFunction()` because the class `System.Web.Security.Roles` does not contain a definition for `MyCustomFunction()` and that's because you did not define a new function in the class

- `MyCustomRoleProvider` and `System.Web.Security.Roles` are TWO different classes which have different functions

[image: System.Web.Security.Roles contains a definition for IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName) (+1 overload)]

**Notice that**: You can not modify or add functions to `System.Web.Security.Roles` as it is write-protected

[image: System.Web.Security.Roles is write protected]

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: I am not instantiateing `Roles` and I think that's part of the problem. In order to use `Roles`you must add `using System.Web.Security;` then you can make calls. So it appears to be some sort of static class maybe? when i hover it the tooltip says it cannot be inherited either...

Comment: @Juventus18 You'll actually need to define a new variable that links to your class to access your class' functions. If you may notice, your class contains `public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)` which `System.Web.Security.Roles` have. Calling `System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole()` will execute a different code block than your class' function. Have a great day :)

Comment: @Juventus18 I've updated my answer for better explanation. Have a great day :)

Comment: I've given you an upvote because you've provided good information, however it still doesn't really answer my question. Since I can make a call to `Roles.IsUserInRole` without creating a new instance of MyCustomRoleProvider, I know there is already an instance out there somewhere, so I'd rather not create another new instance just to call my custom function... although, maybe I'm micro-optimizing...

Comment: @Juventus18 Sorry about that, you must define a new `local variable` to be able to call `MyCustomRoleProvider`. If you want to call `MyCustomFunction()` without defining a new `local variable`, then you have to set `MyCustomFunction()` to a `public static string`.

Comment: @Juventus18 Please notice that when you call `Roles.IsUserInRole` the output will be different than when you call `MyCustomRoleProvider.IsUserInRole()`. Did you try deleting `MyCustomRoleProvider.IsUserInRole()` and checking if you can call `Roles.IsUserInRole`? It will still work!

Comment: @Juventus18 `MyCustomRoleProvider` and `System.Web.Security.Roles` are TWO DIFFERENT CLASSES which have DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS. I hope you understand this. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Roles.IsUserInRole` is a *static method* which has an implementation to pick the current `RoleProvider` and execute it's `IsUserInRole` *instance* method. The type being used internally is not `MyCustomRoleProvider` as a type, but `RoleProvider`. It's effectively this problem:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Foo() { }
}

public class DerivedClass
{
    public virtual void Foo() { }

    public void MoreFoo() { }
}

BaseClass instance = new DerivedClass();
instance.MoreFoo(); // Doesn't compile
```

The class, even though it is a derived version, since it is being used a base type, doesn't know about the implementation you have in your custom provider.

To make it accessible, you can create your own static implementation that internally can do all the calls you want it to:

```
public static class Roles
{
    protected static Lazy<MyCustomProvider> _provider = new Lazy<MyCustomProvider>(() => System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider);

    public static MyCustomProvider Provider { get { return _provider.Value; } }

    public static IsUserInRole(string userName, string roleName)
    {
        return _provider.Value.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName);
    }

    public static MyCustomFunction()
    {
        return _provider.Value.MyCustomFunction();
    }
}
```